# Best practices for passing configuration to a qooxdoo app

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

A complex qooxdoo (desktop) application may need to obtain deployment-specific configuration at startup, for example:

- REST/WebSocket backend URL (which may be different from script/document location);
- branding data;
- enabled/disabled features;
- performance tweaks

and so on. At the moment, we do the following:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        config = {
            key1: "foo",
            key2: "bar",
            key3: "<%= getParameter("myapp.key3") %>"
        };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/myapp.js"></script>
</head>
```

As you've noticed, it's a JSP that provides dynamic `config.key3`, along with static `config.key1` and `config.key2`. I somewhat dislike this approach because 1) `config` top-level object is not recognized in qooxdoo application code, and this results in compiler warning, 2) you can accidentally mess up with another top-level object of same name. Can anyone suggest any better, cleaner way to do the same? It's important that a combination of static and dynamic configuration is supported. For example, a developer hardcodes his specific config into some VCS-ignored JSON file; production environment serves config data from the database; staging/QA environment can use both sources for different parts of config.

The problem is not limited to qooxdoo, of course. I think this may as well be topical for any standalone JavaScript application that may need deployment-specific customization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below method to solve both problems (warning and top level object):

a. in index.html before loading your application's JS:

```
window.qx = { $$environment: {
    "myapp.key1": "foo"
} };
```

b. later in your Qooxdoo application

```
var key1 = qx.core.Environment.get("myapp.key1");
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Any suggestions on how to load a subset of environment keys dynamically? I'm thinking of either loading `$$environment` map with plain XMLHttpRequest in separate script, or using [`qx.data.store.Json`](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.data.store.Json) to load data and [`qx.core.Environment#add`](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.core.Environment~add!method_public) to modify environment at application startup.

Comment: why not just do an rpc call inside your application.js before building anything specific and only start building the specifics once you get the response from the server.

Answer (score 1):

For pre-defined environments I suggest to use normal Qooxdoo configuration, not the hack @geonik presented. Here follows excerpt from normal `config.json`:

```
"config-warnings" : 
{
  "job-shadowing" : ["common", "source-script", "build-script"]
},

"jobs" :
{

  "common" :
  {
    "environment" :
    {
      "appname.version"     : "1.0.0",
      "appname.timeout"     : 30000,
      "appname.analyticsId" : "UA..."
    }
  },

  "source-script" :
  {
    "environment" :
    {
      "appname.serviceUrl"  : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/service",
      "appname.crossDomain" : true
    }
  },

  "build-script" :
  {
    "environment" :
    {
      "appname.serviceUrl"  : "/service",
      "appname.crossDomain" : false
    }
  }

}
```

With the above you have one settings in development build and other settings in production build. You can add more environments, like QA. with other desired settings. Then access them with normal `qx.core.Environment.get`.

I don't suggest to mix runtime settings with Qooxdoo configuration which is inherently static. Just load them on application start with any `qx.io.*` way and handle in your classes.